# MSI cant load .dll Error: 0x8007007E wix installer

Tags: wix

I am trying do this in custom action wix:

```
string sqlConnectionString = @"Server=MyInstanceName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
string script = "...";
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

It work in console app but when I run msi it throw:

> Failed to connect to server MyInstanceName. Could not load DLL
> 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x86.dll': The specified module could not
> be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

When I use Orca I dont see this .dll.

How can i repair that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a library problem Microsoft.SqlServer.Server. I changed library to write sql command on System.Data.SqlClient.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/16048